# How to use fingerprint sdk in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration, fingerprint, zkteco

I am making employee management system and I want to integrate zkteco with my application.
I don't know how to make its sdk works and is there any API or webhook that can provide us with the data for the day/week or month.

zkteco is the software that uses fingerprints with for attendence.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am asking is there is any API or webhook that ZKteco provides for integration tp my rails application.

Comment: https://camsunit.com/product/cams-protocol-update-for-enabling-api-to-biometric-attendance-system.html Pls check if it helps for webhook feature for zkteco attendance systems